# How to edit pathfinding command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm creating a map and the scientist in it is a villager and I want to make him walk on a certain path that I create that goes in a certain direction. Basically I want to modify the 1.8 path finding command creation by Dragnoz [Dragnoz's Video on Entity Pathfinding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a29A6F-M9yo) to work in 1.11. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: What exactly no longer works? It should all still work

Comment: When I input the command /execute @e ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ stone_stairs 0 /tp @e[c=1] ~0.3 ~ ~ -90 10 it tells me "Failed to execute 'detect' as chunkyblocks123" which is my username.

Comment: You should change @e to @e[type=villager] if you want a villager to follow the path. Also, if I recall correctly, Dragnoz was hiding the direction block under the ground, meaning two blocks below rather than 1

Comment: maybe you could explain what isn't working, then we could help you more

Answer (score 1):

I rebuild something similar, here are the four commands I used:

```
/execute @e[r=10] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:stone_stairs 1 /tp @e[r=0] ~-0.3 ~ ~ 90 0
/execute @e[r=10] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:stone_stairs 2 /tp @e[r=0] ~ ~ ~0.3 0 0
/execute @e[r=10] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:stone_stairs 0 /tp @e[r=0] ~0.3 ~ ~ -90 0
/execute @e[r=10] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:stone_stairs 3 /tp @e[r=0] ~ ~ ~-0.3 180 0
```

Note: I just put the commands in command blocks chained together, nice and simple. also `~ ~-1 ~` right after `detect` should be `~ ~-2 ~` if you want the stairs just under the floor.

should work, just have to change `r=10` to something like `type=Villager` and its set up for cobblestone stairs. If you need it for other stairs, just let me know I should be able to get them.

Comment: This works, but remember that the stairs are two blocks beneath the player, not one.

Comment: @JacquesMarais aye, that is true, but as you can see in the answer, I showed which value had to be changed for one block under the floor

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry,  I only saw that now.